# Pairing a date and value with an instance of an object

Tags: python

I am trying to build a program where I have instances of an object with certain values (numbers).
In one part of my program I want to read from a text file in the format:

```
Pig;21-10-22 99.67;21-10-25  96.15;21-10-26  96.58;21-10-27  95.35;21-10-28  94.36;21-10-29  94.00;21-11-01  93.26
Cow;21-10-22 196.10;21-10-25 198.30;21-10-26 197.60;21-10-27 197.40;21-10-28 193.00;21-10-29  194.90
```

I want to assign each date and value to the instance of the object, which will be found using the name in the beginning. which I will do with a dictionary. In this function I will bring in a list of the objects, which has a name and different values associated to it.
I have assigned a `dateValue = {}` dictionary in the class function, so calling `newValue(date, value)` will add to the dictionary like this:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name, value1: value2, value3):
        self.name = name
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2
        self.value3 = value3
        self.dateValue = {}
    
    def newValue(self, date, value):
        self.dateValue[date] = value
```

The question is, how do I do this in main? I am completely stuck and have been for hours, but this is my attempt so far:

```
def readFile(filename, animal_list):
    with open(filename, encoding="utf-8") as file:
        for animal in animal_list:
            for row in file:
                temp = row.strip().split(";")
                print(temp) # Just to see what appears
                    if row == animal.name: # Want to associate the rows to one animal
                        animal.newValue(date, value) # Adding to the dictionary
                                                      # associated with the animal
                                                      # instance
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate by showing code that is actually executable. So little code, so many errors. Where is *newDate*? Where is your class? What does your file really look like? Your most recent addition to the question (the Animal class) contains syntax errors. What would you want to happen if the same date occurred more than once for any given Animal (name)?

Comment: @JCaesar The same date can't appear more than once for ONE animal, according to the text file.

Comment: Can the same Animal name occur more than once in the file? I notice that not all dates in the file have an associated value. How will you handle that?

Comment: That was an error on my side. The same animal namt cant occur more than once in the file. And all the dates should have an associated value.

Answer (score 0):

A simple structure for this problem would be to have a dictionary keyed on the animal name. The animals' associated values could be a list containing instances of a class that manages both the date and its associated value.

Thus, based on your sample data:

```
from collections import defaultdict


class DateValue():
    def __init__(self, dv):
        self.date = dv[0]
        self.value = dv[1]


ANIMALDATA = defaultdict(list)
FILENAME = 'animals.txt'

with open(FILENAME) as adata:
    for line in adata:
        line = line.strip().split(';')
        ANIMALDATA[line[0]] = [DateValue(dv.split()) for dv in line[1:]]

for k, v in ANIMALDATA.items():
    print(f'{k}:')
    print(''.join([f'\tdate={dv.date}, value={dv.value}\n' for dv in v]))
```

**Output:**

```
Pig:
        date=21-10-22, value=99.67
        date=21-10-25, value=96.15
        date=21-10-26, value=96.58
        date=21-10-27, value=95.35
        date=21-10-28, value=94.36
        date=21-10-29, value=94.00
        date=21-11-01, value=93.26

Cow:
        date=21-10-22, value=196.10
        date=21-10-25, value=198.30
        date=21-10-26, value=197.60
        date=21-10-27, value=197.40
        date=21-10-28, value=193.00
        date=21-10-29, value=194.90
```